# Understanding $\tan\theta=\left|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\right|$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

This is the formula for finding the angles between two straight lines:

$$\tan\theta=\left|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\right|$$

$$\implies \tan\theta=\pm \frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}$$

$$\implies \theta=\pm\arctan\left(\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\right)$$

In LHS, only positive values of $\theta$ can be inputted.

Now, according to my book and this [derivation](https://www.math-only-math.com/angle-between-two-straight-lines.html), the $\pm$ has been included to include both the acute and obtuse angles between the straight lines. However, according to [@AmanKushwaha](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4244391/768162), the $\pm$ sign has been included to include the positive (anticlockwise) and negative (clockwise) **acute** angles between the two straight lines. Who is correct?

Moreover,  can't the acute angle measured in the clockwise direction also represent the obtuse angle formed between any two straight lines?

Comment: the acute/obtuse interpretation is the correct one

Comment: First thing, $|x|$ is not same as $\pm x$.Perhaps, you meant this formula $ \small \tan\theta=\left|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\right| \tag{1} \label{1}$ Now what I actually said- You get two values of $m_2$ for a given $m_1$ and an acute inclination angle $\theta$ from $(\ref{1})$ because $\theta$ can be measured in two different directions namely, clockwise and anticlockwise, with respect to the given line with slope $m_1$, resulting in two different equations of lines both making same inclination angle $\theta$.

Comment: @Amankushwaha I edited the formula; is it okay now?

Comment: "In LHS, only positive values of θ can be inputted. " Actually, $\tan{\theta}$ is positive and $\theta$ is acute. So the correction would be "In LHS, θ can take only acute angles".

Comment: I'd suggest you to edit back the question to what you've asked originally otherwise the question asking for $\theta$ being acute or obtuse won't make any sense since now you should've understood that $\theta$ is always the acute angle between the lines in $\small \tan\theta=\left|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\right|$ and for given $m_1$ and $m_2$, you get exactly one $\theta$ and that will always belong to $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ but for given acute $\theta$ and $m_1$ , you'll get two values of $m_2$. This equation $\small \tan\theta=\pm \frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}$, however, yields....

Comment: ... two different values of $\theta$ as mentioned in the answer below by @GregMartin . Read this comment I added in the answer of your previous question: 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4244257/intuition-behind-getting-two-straight-lines-as-result?noredirect=1#comment8822539_4244391

Comment: Both interpretations are correct, and they are actually identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the equation can be rewritten as
$$
\theta = \arctan\biggl( \pm\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2} \biggr).
$$
The answer to your question depends on the convention being used for the values of the arctangent function:

- If one declares that $\arctan x$ always lies between $-\frac\pi2$ and $\frac\pi2$, then the formula yields the positive and negative acute angles formed by the two lines;
- If one declares that $\arctan x$ always lies between $0$ and $\pi$, then the formula yields the acute and obtuse angles made by the two lines.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! Could you please look into the linked question in my question? It'd be of great help: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4244391/768162