# Is the angle between $px+qy+12=0$ and $px+qy+20=0$ $0$ or $\pi$?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, angle

*This question came in the Rajshahi University admission exam 2010-11*

Q) Angle between $px+qy+12=0$ and $px+qy+20=0$ is-

(a) $\frac{\pi}{3}$

(b) $\frac{\pi}{2}$

(c) $\pi$

(d) None of the above

**My attempt:**

$$\tan\theta=\pm\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}$$

$$\tan\theta=\pm\frac{-\frac{p}{q}+\frac{p}{q}}{1+\frac{p^2}{q^2}}$$

$$\tan\theta=0$$

$$\tan\theta=n\pi,n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Now, $\theta=0,\pi,...$

There is $\pi$ in (c), so I'll go with (c). The third-party question bank agrees with me that (c) is the correct answer. [However, I saw the following on the internet:](https://qr.ae/pvMAop)

> An angle is formed when one line intersect another line in some
> specific manner . And the degree of the angle is determined by how the
> lines intersect each other .
>
> Two parellel line never intersect each other . So no angle is formed
> between them .
>
> So its safe to say the angle between two lines is undefined or zero
> degrees.

As "undefined" or "0" has not been given in the options, should I go with (d)?

Comment: I think directed line segments, say +X axis and -X axis, would have an angle $\pi$ between them.

Comment: Two distinct parallel lines do not define an angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [my Answer to your previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4253493/21813):

“**when two straight lines intersect, the angle between them is uniquely specified by some angle in $\mathbf{[0,90^\circ].}$** This is in fact the standard way to specify the angle between two straight lines.”

Adding to that:

- **the angle between two coincident lines is** $\mathbf{0^\circ},$ while
- **the angle between two parallel lines is undefined**.

On the other hand, the angle between two nonzero Euclidean vectors sharing a common $n$-dimensional space is always defined (and lying in $[0,180^\circ]$), since these vectors are “portable” in space.

Comment: When you consider two parallel lines,  gradients are same because they make equal angles with positive direction of X axis.  Using that you can obtain Tanθ = 0 , where θ is the angle between the two lines. Now you get θ as a integer multiple of π.  Since you have infinitely many solutions can't we say angle between two parallel lines is indeterminate rather than undefined?

Comment: There's no way to define an angle with just two parallel lines; for example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle) says, "an angle is the figure formed by two rays sharing a common vertex/endpoint." The angle between two parallel lines is thus undefined (consequently: indeterminate).

Comment: If you are the downvoter, then ,since I'd edited the Answer after that, feel free to revert it.

Comment: P.S. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4504599/21813) currently-bountied Question may be of interest. -)

Comment: usually I don't downvote questions or answers because I think it may create negative thoughts in others minds. I just wanted to clarify the issue only.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  The lines are parallel, so the answer is "none of the above".